# Including the validation set in the training set

Tags: time-series, validation

I observed this in a Kaggle M5 competition [notebook](https://www.kaggle.com/kyakovlev/m5-three-shades-of-dark-darker-magic/notebook) (cell 7, some explanation in cell 4) that inspired the [competition winner](https://github.com/Mcompetitions/M5-methods/tree/master/Code%20of%20Winning%20Methods/A1), who used the same methodology to create "fake" validation data. Unfortunately, I was not able to grasp the intuition behind this approach. Is this something commonly done in practice, or specific to the M5 data? The author of the answer to [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/391317/when-the-validation-set-is-a-subset-of-the-training-set) appears skeptical as well.